# Clone tables including more than one pk

Tags: mysql

I'd like to clone a table onto another by these statements:

```
INSERT clone_table1
SELECT alias.* FROM table1 alias
INNER JOIN table2 b
on alias.pidm = b.user
WHERE alias.pidm LIKE "2016%"
AND b.userstate = 30;
```

Yes it does work well, until there are more than one `alias.pidm` on `table1`.

**table1:**

```
id | pidm | field1 | field2
---------------------------
 1 |   5  |   aa   |  bb
 2 |   5  |   cc   |  dd
 3 |   5  |   ee   |  ff
```

**table2:**

```
user | field1 | userstate
-------------------------
 5   |   kk   |    30
 6   |   jj   |    40
```

so, the only field i can identify each other is between `table1.pidm` and `table2.user`.

**So the question is:** How can i insert all `where table1.pidm=5 and table2.userstate=30` rows into `clone_table1` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not clear,what doenst work?What are the expected results?

Comment: the sql query i'm executing is just cloning one row from table1. I'd like to clone all values from table1, where their pidm is 5 and their userstate is 30 on table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with the query as following:

```
INSERT clone_table1
SELECT alias.* FROM table1 alias
INNER JOIN table2 b
on alias.pidm = b.user
WHERE alias.pidm LIKE "2016%"
AND b.userstate= 30;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT clone_table1
SELECT alias.* FROM table1 alias
LEFT JOIN table2 b
on alias.pidm = b.user AND b.userstate = 30
WHERE alias.pidm LIKE "2016%"
```

Comment: sorry, but this one inserts all values from table1 into clone_table1

Comment: @blankBird_ Show expected results in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT clone_table SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.pidm=5 AND table2.userstate =  (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.userstate=30)` 
not sure if it will work but you can try using sub-queries. It's been too long since i touch on sql. Here is the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) that might help